# No redirection after successful angular form validation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-reactive-forms

Today, I encountered a problem with angular routing after successful validation of Angular reactive form. All I want to achieve is validate passwords fields in my form and in case success redirect toward another component `('/customers')` or in case that passwords are not the same we should do nothing and give a chance to the user to retype proper passwords again.

RegistrationComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  registerForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  email$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private customerService: CustomerService, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      surname: ['', Validators.required],
      phoneNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      nip: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
    }, {
      validator: MustMatch('password', 'confirmPassword')
    });
  }

  get form() {
    return this.registerForm.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    const registeredCustomer: RegistrationForm = {

      username: this.registerForm.controls.username.value,
      email: this.registerForm.controls.email.value,
      name: this.registerForm.controls.name.value,
      surname: this.registerForm.controls.surname.value,
      phoneNumber: this.registerForm.controls.phoneNumber.value,
      password: this.registerForm.controls.password.value,
      confirmPassword: this.registerForm.controls.confirmPassword.value,

    };


    this.email$ = this.customerService
    .register(registeredCustomer)
    .pipe(map(customer => customer.email));

    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
      return;
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate((['/customers'])), 5000);
    }

    alert('User successfully registered' + JSON.stringify(this.registerForm.value));

  }

}
```

RegistrationComponent.html

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h3>Fill in the form below to complete the registration process </h3>
        <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.username.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && form.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="form.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.name.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && form.name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="form.name.errors.required">Customer name is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Surname</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="surname" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.surname.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && form.surname.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="form.surname.errors.required">Customer surname is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="phoneNumber" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.phoneNumber.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && form.phoneNumber.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="form.phoneNumber.errors.required">Phone number is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.email.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && form.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="form.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="form.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.password.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && form.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="form.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="form.password.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && form.confirmPassword.errors }" />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && form.confirmPassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="form.confirmPassword.errors.required">Confirm Password is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="form.confirmPassword.errors.mustMatch">Passwords must match</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was based on this tutorial: [Registration tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/07/angular-7-reactive-forms-validation-example)

but after small modification, my current solution is not working properly.

I was trying to replace this

```
    setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate((['/customers'])), 5000);
```

infront of:

```
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
```

and checking if boolean value `submitted = false` but it didn't yield the desired result.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Edit: Stackblitz link for application.

[component](https://angular-y3jci7.stackblitz.io/registration)

[stackblitz editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y3jci7?embed=1&file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Have you verified your routes are defined properly?

Comment: @Narm, a console is clear. I am receiving only fields of the customer which is currently registered.

`
{id: 30, name: "MARTIN", surname: "MARTIN", email: "martin.martin@o2.pl"}
`

Comment: If you add console.log() statements inside your if/else, is it actually getting to the else statement? Also where/how is `email$` being used? With an `async` pipe?

Comment: It looks like you may have have too many parentheses. Try this `this.router.navigate(['/customers'])`

Comment: `if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
      console.log('bad');
      return;
    }
    console.log('good');
    setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate((['/customers'])), 5000);
    console.log('good1')`

In this scenario when I am putting the same, proper password, I am receiving in the console: 
bad

@Narm Unfortunately, that did not solve a problem.

@AlexanderStaroselsky, I will try to use this in a moment to pass it to pop up like: User with the email registered. Sorry for blurring code with this piece of redundant code.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproduction of your issue in stackblitz

Comment: Ill remove the downvote once you add the stackblitz link. As it is, its impossible to help you as people will have to guess what is going on in your app without a minimal repro

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Luckily, I finally finished copy-paste process toward stackblitz. Actually, this can simplify the process of diagnosis. 

Link to stackblitz:

[link](https://angular-y3jci7.stackblitz.io/registration)

and 

[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y3jci7?embed=1&file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts)

I hope that now this will be helpful. 

Anyway, boostrap dependency is missing but I hope that will not be a visual problem.

Comment: If you edit your question and add the link I will be able to remove the down vote

Comment: I did not realize that I suppose to add a link in the main post aside from comment section. Now it seems that everything is good.

Thanks for commitment.
@Jota.Toledo

Comment: Your blitz is broken. As it is, your form will never be valid as you arent setting the `nip` member.....

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, oh, you right. Actually, I missed this field in the form and did not realize that can have so big impact. What do you mean that blitz is broken? You need `/registration' path to get into this component. These are my first steps with angular, I hope that it will be better with each step. Anyway, I would be thankful for an explanation what in your opinion is a reason to downvote a question.

Answer (score 2):

We've been working at work on a library to handle forms easily and with also more type safety (for both TS and HTML!). This library is called `ngx-sub-form` and you can find it here: https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form

Using `ngx-sub-form`, I've made a demo of your app that you can try here:
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-genpiv

Now, some explanations.

First, we want to define a proper interface for your form (type safety for the win!):

```
export interface RegistrationForm {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
  nip: string;
  password: string;
  confirmPassword: string;
}
```

Then we create all the components we need for the app:
- `app/app.component.ts`
- `app/registration/registration.component.ts`
- `app/registration/registration-form/registration-form.component.ts`
- `app/customers.component.ts`

Now we need to define the routing for our app. Our `app.module.ts` should look like the following:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/registration',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'registration',
    component: RegistrationComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'customers',
    component: CustomersComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)],
  declarations: [AppComponent, RegistrationFormComponent, RegistrationComponent, CustomersComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And `app.component.html` should simply be `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

`RegistrationComponent` will act as a smart component. It will inject the router and just wait for the form to be sent. That component **doesn't** want to be aware of the form itself, just the object that has been sent.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  public register(registrationForm: RegistrationForm): void {
    // here you probably want to inject a `RegistrationService` instead of the `Router`
    // and call a method that will make an XHR call to your backend and on success
    // would do that `navigate` from the service too
    // for the sake of simplicity here I'm just doing the navigate directly
    this.router.navigate(['/customers']);
  }
}
```

And its HTML:

```
<app-registration-form (register)="register($event)"></app-registration-form>
```

`RegistrationFormComponent` will be the component responsible to handle the form. That component is the only one that needs to use `ngx-sub-form` library.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration-form',
  templateUrl: './registration-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration-form.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationFormComponent extends NgxSubFormComponent<RegistrationForm> {
  @Output() register: EventEmitter<RegistrationForm> = new EventEmitter();

  protected getFormControls(): Controls<RegistrationForm> {
    return {
      username: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      name: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      surname: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      phoneNumber: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      nip: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      confirmPassword: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    }
  }

  protected getFormGroupControlOptions(): FormGroupOptions<RegistrationForm> {
    return {
      validators: [
        formGroup => {
          if (formGroup.value.password !== formGroup.value.confirmPassword) {
            return {
              passwordsMustMatch: true,
            };
          }

          return null;
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  public onSubmit(): void {
    this.register.emit(this.formGroupValues)
  }
}
```

Things to notice here:

- `export class RegistrationFormComponent extends NgxSubFormComponent<RegistrationForm>` we're extending `NgxSubFormComponent` and we pass our form interface. That will provide us a lot utilities and also some type safety
- The method `getFormControls` expects you to basically provide an object to create your form. I think it's self explanatory because it looks like the object you'd pass when creating a `FormGroup`
- `getFormGroupControlOptions` is a hook provided by `NgxSubFormComponent` that allows you to set validators or asyncValidators at the `FormGroup` level
- Finally, the `onSubmit` method is the one that'll be called when the user clicks on the `Register` button (once the form is fully valid)

Now, the last missing piece is the form HTML (for simplicity I'll only display in the response the first field and the password check because everything in between is pretty much the same)

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h3>Fill in the form below to complete the registration process</h3>
        <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" [formControlName]="formControlNames.username" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': formGroupErrors?.username }" />
            <div *ngIf="formGroupErrors && formGroupControls.username.touched" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="formGroupErrors?.username?.required">Username is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          ...


          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="text" [formControlName]="formControlNames.confirmPassword" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': formGroupErrors?.confirmPassword }" />
            <div *ngIf="formGroupErrors && formGroupControls.confirmPassword.touched" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="formGroupErrors?.confirmPassword?.required">Confirm Password is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="formGroupErrors?.formGroup?.passwordsMustMatch">Passwords must match</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">Register</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Things to notice from the HTML:

- `<form [formGroup]="formGroup"` we haven't defined the `formGroup` ourselves. It's been created by `NgxSubFormComponent`
- `<input type="text" [formControlName]="formControlNames.username"` the `formControlNames` property is also defined by `NgxSubFormComponent` and its main purpose is to bring some type safety! If you try to put `formControlNames.random` you'll get a run time error, but also a Typescript error when compiling with AOT!
- `<div *ngIf="formGroupErrors?.username?.required">` the property `formGroupErrors` is also provided by `NgxSubFormComponent` and gives you access to the form errors. Best part is that it works with nested sub forms and is also type safe! Even though here we don't have any sub form, I invite you to check the Github page of `ngx-sub-form` to learn more about that

The app is now fully ready and has a lot of type safety! Any refactor impacting the main interface will also require you to update the form (TS + HTML) otherwise Typescript will throw errors around.

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Then once it's valid:

[image]

And then when we click on register:

[image]

Don't forget to check out the live example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-genpiv

**Edit:**

If you want to go further, I've just published a blog post to explain a lot of things about forms and ngx-sub-form here https://dev.to/maxime1992/building-scalable-robust-and-type-safe-forms-with-angular-3nf9

Answer (score 0):

To activate the routing you must inject the routing module in the app.module.ts (i.e root module).
Also define the path for the route in your routing module file as :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'customers' , component: CustomersComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Aslo don't forgrt to include `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag because its where the child view will be loaded after the routing is successfull.

Comment: I think that is not a problem with Route because so far my AppRoutingModule.ts looks like: 

`const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'customers', component: CustomerListComponent},
  {path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}), FormsModule],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}` 

If I am wrong, please make me aware

Comment: You can use the method .navigateByUrl() for absolute path routing instead of .navigate().. this might help